# C3 - Add Custom Labels on Line Graph

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I have a C3 chart,

I would like to add a label on each point reading its y value with a percentage symbol appended to it.

e.g. 400%.

There is a solution for bar charts

```
labels: {
                format: {
                    y: d3.format("$,")
                    //y: function (v, id) { return "Custom Format: " + id; }
                }
```

But this doesn't work for line graphs.

There is also good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619766/is-there-any-way-to-change-a-label-with-c3js) on custom labels for bar charts, however, this doesn't seem to transfer to line charts.

There is this good [answer](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754239/how-to-change-tooltip-content-in-c3js) on custom tooltips, but I can't work out how to do custom labels in a line graph.

Attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/7kYJu/6547/

Also, for some reason using `%` will prevent the graph from appearing, whereas `$` will work, e.g

```
y: d3.format("$,")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
`var chart = c3.generate({
   data: {
                columns: [
                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                    ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
                ],
                type: 'line',
                labels: {
                    format: {
                        data1: d3.format("$,")
                        //data1: function (v, id) { return "Custom Format: " + id; }
                    }
                }
            }
});`
```

it should be the data array and not the axis to be mentioned as key in format object